# ActiveRecord::Base.connection vs ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the difference between `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` and `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` ?

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection` - return current connection

`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` - setup connection

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` is responsible for making a new connection pool to a database using the passed in options hash. This determines what connections `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` will create.

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection` on the other hand will attempt to reuse a connection from the currently defined connection pool **in the current thread** and if it doesn't find one, will establish a new one.

Generally, if you need to get a connection instance to the database, use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`. If you need to change what database you are connecting to, or any of the database connection settings, first call `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` and then any calls that need a connection will use those new settings.

Comment: If I want to create/fetch some entries to/from remote database from a ruby script using ActiveRecord, so in that case can I use it?

Comment: @akshay Yes, you can use `establish_connection` for that.